# Error with Go Get for Protobuf in Dockerfile

Tags: go, docker

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang
RUN apt-get update
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}
```

This generates this error:

```
package github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}: invalid github.com/ import path "github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}"
```

But, if I take out that `RUN` directive, and just load up `/bin/bash` in the docker container, I can run the `go get` command just fine.

What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around the command? Not sure just what's going on here but I suspect some shell string quoting / expansion weirdness. By default `RUN` uses `/bin/sh -c`; I would think it would be smart enough to quote the argument, but maybe not.

Comment: The shell executing the RUN line is a basic `/bin/sh`, and doesn't do the brace expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if I use another shell, like bash, and put double quotes for the `go` command

`RUN bash -c "go get github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}"`

By the way, you can do all in only one RUN, see Dockerfiles best practices

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: This answer worked! Although the other one explains what's going on :P

Answer (score 5):

It's happening because the default shell is *not* `/bin/bash`, it's `sh`. You have two possible solutions, either you can explicitly define a shell in your RUN command like so:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}"]
```

Or you can change the shell that `RUN` uses by default like so:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/shell

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this answer didn't work for me - I got this error: `/bin/bash: go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ye, I didn't have time to test it so it's an approximation :p Will test today and fix the exact command.

Comment: OK tested. First way worked fine, second way now edited, just needed the "-c" added to the SHELL directive.